# .lib sub-dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dependencies

I'm creating a small .lib

This small .lib needs some other .lib.
I would like for my small .lib to contain the "code" of these other .lib.
Then the application which will use my small .lib won't need these other .lib.

I'm using Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you put all the projects in one solution.  Right-click the "small lib" project, Properties, Librarian, General.  Add the dependent libraries to the Additional Dependencies setting.  To make sure you get the debug build of them in your Debug configuration and the release build in your Release configuration, make them look like

```
$(OutDir)foo1.lib $(OutDir)foo2.lib
```

Etcetera.  Right-click again, Project Dependencies and make sure that the dependent library projects are ticked so they are built before the "small lib" project.

If the dependent .libs are already built by a project that is not in the solution then just add them to the Additional Dependencies setting.  Switch to the Release build configuration and repeat.